# There's been a [mismatch] in expected tag usage

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I came across the tag [mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mismatch) today, which seems to not really be in line with normal tagging guidelines. Its usage guidance already implies it's ambiguous, which is normally a great early indicator it doesn't belong:

> Mismatch refers to a failure to correspond or match. This can be ambiguous. More-specific tags such as [type-mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-mismatch) or [inputmismatchexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inputmismatchexception) may be more appropriate.

The wiki goes on to give the Oxford Dictionary definition and then states *again* that it's ambiguous:

> The Oxford Dictionary defines mismatch:
>
> - (n) A bad match; a failure to correspond or match, a discrepancy.
> - (v) To match (in various senses) badly, unsuitably, or incorrectly.
>
> This term applies to computing in many senses that are consistent with the definition of the word, so as a tag it is **ambiguous**.
>
> Where appropriate, a more specific tag should be used. For example:
>
> - [type-mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-mismatch)
> - [inputmismatchexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inputmismatchexception)

I suggest that the tag be burninated.

#### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Not really, no. A mismatch could be about anything such as a types, colours, values, behaviour, etc. It's ambiguous and the tag's own content agrees.

#### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

On its own, no. A type mismatch error would be on topic (though that has its own tags), but it could be used in many contexts where the subject matter isn't about programming.

#### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, as it's ambiguous and could be off-topic.

#### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, because anything could mismatch, and how those are handled can be wildly different.

Comment: This tag clearly has a mishmash of all sorts of uses.

Comment: It should be burninated, after the strike!

Comment: Only 468 questions currently

Comment: Certainly not the worst offender in burnination history, @Dijkgraaf